# If $M$ is a finitely generated module, $S$ is a submodule of $M$, $M/S$ is free, and $M\cong S \oplus M/S$, why must $S$ be finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am working through Rotman's Theorem 9.3 in Advanced Modern Algebra. If $M$ is finitely generated, $S$ is a submodule of $M$, and $M/S$ is free, we have that $M\cong S\oplus M/S$. My professor told me that because $S$ is a direct summand of a finitely generated module, then $S$ itself has to be finitely generated. I am wondering why he chose to word it like this instead of saying that since $S$ is a submodule of $M$ and $M$ is finitely generated, then $S$ must be finitely generated, too. I do not see explicitly why his statement is true (even though it makes sense intuitively).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $M/S$ is free is completely irrelevant. Any homomorphic image of a finitely generated module is finitely generated as well.

More precisely, let $f\colon M\to N$ be a surjective homomorphism. If $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is a finite set of generators for $M$, then $\{f(x_1),\dots,f(x_n)\}$ is a set of generators for $N$. Can you prove it? Of course $f$ being surjective is the key.

A direct summand is a homomorphic image.

Your argument fails: a submodule of a finitely generated module need not be finitely generated. Standard example: take the ring $R=k[x_0,x_1,\dotsc]$ of polynomials over the field $k$ in infinitely many variables. Then the ideal generated by the variables is not a finitely generated $R$-module, whereas $R$ is obviously finitely generated as an $R$-module.

A module such that every submodule thereof is finitely generated indeed has a special name: it is called a Noetherian module. If the ring is Noetherian (as a module over itself), then every finitely generated module is Noetherian. The ring in the above example is not Noetherian.